# Windows 7 does not recognize LG E2250 monitor when connected with RGB

Tags: windows-7, external-display, lg-monitor

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T410 and an LG monitor E2250 (1080p, so should support 1920×1080). I try to connect the monitor using the RGB connector and use it as an external monitor. The problem is that Windows 7 only shows the monitor as a non PNP monitor and will not allow me to set the resolution to 1650X1050. 
I installed the driver for the monitor manually, but it still did not help, even after a restart.

I might add that the external monitor does not display the BIOS messages at boot.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure the laptop supports an external monitor of that resolution?

Comment: @RJFalconer - It's a Thinkpad. It supports that resolution. (VGA does go that high, right?)

Comment: wikipedia says VGA should support 1280x1024px @85 Hz (160 MHz) and up to 2048x1536px @85 Hz (388 MHz). Try updating graphics drivers perhaps?

Comment: I checked for a driver update and got the message that I am using the latest version. I think I am just going to buy an HDMI cable and be done with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a custom resolution through the NVIDIA controller for the card. Using the native resolution for the screen works without problem (1920x1080).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem but I do not know which values to insert in the control panel. Can you help me? It's concerning the last image! http://superuser.com/questions/525215/secondary-monitor-does-not-display-native-resolution

Comment: Sorry, I am no longer in possession of that computer and don't remember any values I used....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the LG E2250-v monitor with an Acer notebook running Win7 Pro 64-bit. Win7 Dsisplay settings is a no-go.
I finally installed a Graphics Controller (I had Intel Card in the notebook) and in the Intel Graphics and Meia Control Panel (taskbar right side bottom corner) I could adjust resolution. Forget about the Display settings in Windows 7, it just does not work. Install or go to your installed graphics card controller. It should work properly.