# 1920x1080 native resolution disappeared

Tags: windows-7, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Secondary monitor does not display native resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/525215/secondary-monitor-does-not-display-native-resolution)

I use an on-board GPU on my computer (GForce 420 GT) with 2 screens, one is connected via DVI and the other VGA. For the past 2 years the screen resolution on those screens was 1920x1080 (which was the their native resolution). Last week I updated the Nvidia driver to 310.90 (latest) since then the Nvidia control panel decided that the native resolution on the VGA connected screen is 1793x1080, not only that but when I choose this resolution the screen goes blank, if I choose a lower resolution the screen is shown but everything is blurry, what to do?

I already tried re-installing the driver and also roll-back

I use win7 pro 32bit

Comment: First of all, +1 for a good clear question. Now, what does roll back mean, driver roll back or system restore :)?

Comment: roll-back means driver roll-back in the device manager, I can't system restore

Comment: Can you please confirm why not, I assume it hasn't been set up or do you mean it didn't succeed?

Comment: What happens when you set the resolution in the normal Windows dialog? Why does the nVidia control panel have to get involved?

Comment: @ta.speot.is In the windows dialog the 1920x1080 disappeared the best one was 1793x1080 and like i said when i choose that the screen goes blank

Answer (score 0):

I have had graphic card issues, rolling drivers back etc has not always helped.

I suggest a system restore (to a point before you made the update last week!).

Comment: That was my first thought also but I cant system restore since the Nvidia update didn't set a restore point (I don't know why) and the last system restore is like from 2 months ago

Comment: And can I assume that rolling back that far is undesirable? If it helps, I've rolled back much further and other than performing another Windows update, there was no negativity for me.

Comment: If that will be my last option **or** if you can guarantee me that that will work, I'll do it. basically what I'm doing here is exploring my options if you guys will tell my system restore is the last and only so system restore it, but we're better then that aren't we?

Comment: It's the world of IT, nothing is guaranteed! However, the only other option I can think of is, finding an old driver and installing it, or contacting NVidea direct. Some one else may have an idea, but if it were me, I'd do it. The problem of a roll back is, of course, it doesn't get to the route of why!

Comment: of course nothing is guaranteed! I only added it has a joke anyway I tried Nvidia support forum no one answered other then that like I said I'm exploring my options before system restore. btw i rather system restore then to install an old driver on top of the new one

Comment: @RoeyNissim :) By the way, please always add the @ before a name (eg @dave) in a comment, this will alert that user directly. You would have to remove the current driver before putting on the old, but I know why you would be wary. However, you now have another answer which may be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom resolution in nVidia control panel under 'Change Resolution' for the display on the VGA output and use that. That should work.

Comment: I tried to create a custom resolution and the reaction was very strange it was like it tried to show the custom resolution 1920x1080 on top of the old resolution say 1680x1050. I know it sounds odd but basically what I got is a smaller blurry screen.

Comment: So, 1680x1050 with a black border basically? Did you try setting the scaling to Full Screen instead of aspect ratio under 'Adjust desktop size and position'? Also, restart your machine once you have changed to the custom resolution. I've had a PC in the past that would not display properly after a resolution change til a restart.

Comment: OK changing the scale to full screen did make the screen bigger but it still blurry and i don't think its 1920x1080 all we did is magnify 1680x1050

Comment: What's the model of your monitor?